# How to update data by ID?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8

I have insert-code as below:

```
public void insertData(string TimeStart, string TimeEnd, string AppName)
{
    try
    {
        event newdb = new event
        {
            TimeStart = TimeStart,
            TimeEnd = TimeEnd,
            AppName = "",
        };
        db.listdata.InsertOnSubmit(newdb);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string str = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

It inserts successful but I don't know how to update the data.

Answer (score 2):

to update it all you need to do is get the object. change some values and then call `SubmitChanges()` something like

```
var itemUpdate = db.listdata.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID);
if(itemUpdate != null)
{
    itemUpdate.AppName = "New name";
    // update other properties here

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Could youu tell me after insert sucessful how to get ID has just insert.

Comment: @user3409461 it will be part of the `itemUpdate` object, you can get it by going `itemUpdate.ID` in your example it would be `newdb.ID` or whatever the primary key field is called in your model

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have set ID as primary key, because it needs a primary key and do like this,

Filter the existing data using your ID and then update with new values and call SubmitChanges()

```
try
{
   var Query= db.listdata.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID);
   Query.TimeStart = "NewValue";
   Query.TimeEnd  = "NewValue";
   Query.AppName = "",
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   string str = ex.Message.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the object you want to update from the DB. Code might look like this:

```
var eventToUpdate = from e in db.Events.
                    where e.ID == someId
                    select e;
```

or using LinQ-method:

```
var eventToUpdate = db.Events.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == someId);
```

And then you can updated the properties (just like with the insert):

```
eventToUpdate.TimeStart = newTimeStart;
eventToUpdate.TimeEnd = newTimeEnd;
eventToUpdate.AppName = "";
```

Finally commit the changes:

```
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Of course you'll have to validate input and check if the instance with given id exists. Do this by checking if the object from the DB is not `null`:

```
if(eventToUpdate != null)
    //update the event
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newObj = db.listdata.where(a => a.yourKey == key).FirstOrDefault();

//Here you have your data in newObj

//now you can manipulate it accordingly

//eg:
newObj.property="your value";

db.SubmitChanges();
```